# Inner tent - Vango F10 Xenon UL 2

Tags: camping, tents

Some time ago I bought [Vango F10 Xenon UL 2 tent](https://www.vango.co.uk/gb/tents/1046-f10-xenon-ul-2.html). Had no chance to use it yet as I had to cancel the trip I was planning on using it on. Now I'm planning something new, but as it's going to be in some warmer areas with no rain I was thinking about using just the inner tent and pitch it without flysheet.

- Is it possible to pitch just the inner part of this tent?
- Does it makes sense? I guess it would protect me from insects, etc, but what would be other advantages of using just the inner tent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tent is a tunnel tent with the poles inserted into sleeves in the exterior flysheet and the inner tent suspended from inside the flysheet. This means that there is no practical way of pitching the inner tent alone without the flysheet.

You could use the flysheet alone without the inner tent to save weight.